# starting a service in Android

Tags: android, service

I know that the best to start service is

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class  ));
```

How can I send my application context also when I am starting a new service?

Comment: What are you considering an "application context" to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys i able to solve my problem by this line from my service

```
this.context=this.createPackageContext("com.myPackage", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY );
```

Thanks for all those suggestion though.

/minhaz

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that?

A Service itself is a context, use `this` when you need a context in a Service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:-

```
Context mycontext;
mycontext = getBaseContext();
startService(new Intent(mycontext, MyService.class  ));
```

Long winded code, but easy to understand, if this is what your looking for?

Comment: That is not significantly different -- and definitely no better -- than the code the OP presently has.